# SAML 2.0 + Keycloak + Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, saml-2.0, spring-saml

We're trying to set up a Keycloak locally with docker to be able to login to our application with SAML 2.0.

Versions used:

- Keyloak 18.0.0
- Spring Boot 2.6.3

The access to an endpoint forwards to Keycloak, but we always face the same error (which is available in the keycloak-console):
`WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-15) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=my-app, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.18.0.1, error=client_not_found, reason=Cannot_match_source_hash`

WebSecurityConfig:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.metadata.OpenSamlMetadataResolver;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.servlet.filter.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2MetadataFilter;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;

    public WebSecurityConfig(RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository) {
        this.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository = relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver defaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository);
        Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(defaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());

        http
                .saml2Login(withDefaults())
                .addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

Relevant dependencies in pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.yml (relevant parts):

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          saml:
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: http://localhost:8080/realms/my-app
              verification:
                  - certificate-location: "classpath:saml-certificate/keycloak.cert"
              singlesignon:
                url: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-app/protocol/saml
                sign-request: false
```

I can also provide relevant parts of our Keycloak configuration, but as the export is quite big I'd need to know which parts are relevant.

Is there something missing in the application.yml or do we need another approach to configure it?

Comment: Here GitHub example integration Spring boot 2 SAML2 keycloak 18 : 
https://github.com/HenryXiloj/spring-boot-security-saml2.0-keycloak

Answer (score 0):

You should set correct name of your Client ID in keycloak server`s client settings.
Client ID must be same as issuer in SAML request. Spring-security-saml uses ['{baseUrl}/saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registrationId}'](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/saml2.html) pattern, in your case it should looks like 'http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/saml'